# Упал DHCP на прошивке DD WRT

Tags: dhcp, dd-wrt

День добрый, специалисты. Залил на TP-link wr842 DD WRT, порадовался функционалу, отпустил в ребут и... Всё) Нет определения DHCP, сеть тупо посылает пакеты вникуда.

Есть ли какая-то возможность оживить девайс, может кто-то знает сервисное меню, или что-то подобное у ТПшек. Заранее благодарю

Answer (score 1):

TL-WR842 поддерживает восстановление прошивки через специальную утилиту, работающую на основе tftp-сервера. Для восстановления роутера нужно сделать следующее:

1. Скачать утилиту [Tftpd v 32.400](http://tftpd32.jounin.net/download/tftpd32.400.zip).
2. Скачать последнюю прошивку для TL-WR842ND с официального сайта компании TP-LINK, разархивировать её и изменить имя файла на «wr842ndv1_tp_recovery»(«.bin» разрешение должно остаться). [TL-WR842ND_V1_120424](http://www.tp-linkru.com/support/download/?model=TL-WR842ND&version=V1#tbl_j).
3. Распакуйте архив с программой. Файл прошивки разместите в одной папке с программой tftp32.
4. Подключите роутер к компьютеру с помощью сетевого кабеля. Измените IP-адрес Вашего «подключения по локальной сети» на 192.168.1.66, Маску оставьте 255.255.255.0, поля Шлюз и DNS-сервера оставьте пустыми.
5. Запустите утилиту от имени администратора. Проверьте чтобы в программе был выбран нужный сетевой интерфейс. И при нажатии кнопки Show Dir, в показавшемся списке был файл с прошивкой wr842ndv1_tp_recovery.bin.
6. Включите роутер, затем удерживайте кнопку WPS/Reset Button пока не загорится индикатор USB.
7. Утилита TFTP32 автоматически загрузит прошивку на маршрутизатор.
8. Если процесс загрузки не начинается, то перезагрузите роутер, не выключая программу.После этого не забудьте вернуть получение IP-адреса автоматически и подождать некоторое время, пока маршрутизатор перезагрузится и ПК получит настройки.

P.S. Бонус.

Лучшая прошивка после восстановления заводской - ddwrt v24 SP1 (Build10020).Взять ее можно здесь: [http://www.dd-wrt.com](http://www.dd-wrt.com/)

Удачи!

Comment: Я прошу прощения, но не люблю я эти ВТР-вские прошивки! Если мне чего надо - я туда терминалом залезаю, и правлю руками конфиги. Там ведь тот же Линукс!

Answer (score 0):

Перед тем, как заливать новую прошивку, всегда желательно сохранить старую, на всякий пожарный случай. Специально для тех, кто забыл это сделать, некоторая старая прошивка хранится на диске, который был в комплекте с роутером, откуда и можно её восстановить! И пожалуйста, не надо экспериментировать с роутерными прошивкакми, если вы не знаете(а судя по вопросу, так это и есть), как они работают! Если девайс работает - не надо его трогать, без лишних на то причин! Это - принцип Оккама.

А если уж и диск потеряли - то родную прошивку всегда можно скачать с сайта фирмы!

Answer (score 0):

А не пробовали прописать параметры сетевого интерфейса на ПК вручную и зайти в конфигуратор роутера?